# Issue with os.system() in python3

Tags: python, bash, awk

I am trying to develop a pipeline which involves running a UNIX command which I am doing inside a os.system() call. The call fails when python code is executed. The issue is when I copy paste and run the same code directly from the UNIX terminal it runs fine. I am not sure what is doing wrong here. This the os.system() command.

```
cmd="paste "
cmd+="<(awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' "+DATA_DIRECTORY_y2h+"/data/trimmed_reads/S"+str(library)+"_STAR_transcriptome_vector_freeAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam.idxstats) "
cmd+="<(awk '{print $3}' "+DATA_DIRECTORY_y2h+"/data/trimmed_reads/S"+str(library)+"_STAR_transcriptome_trimmed_vector_containingAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam.idxstats) "
cmd+="| awk '$3>0 && $4>0'|awk '{a[NR]=$0;x+=(b[NR]=$3)}END{while(++i<=NR)print a[i]\" \"100*b[i]/x}'|sort -grk5,5 > "
cmd+=DATA_DIRECTORY_y2h+"/data/trimmed_reads/S"+str(library)+"_STAR_transcript_read_coverage.txt"
```

and when I print it out the command is

```
paste <(awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' /home/bigdata/sagnik/y2h//data/trimmed_reads/S1_STAR_transcriptome_vector_freeAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam.idxstats) <(awk '{print $3}' /home/bigdata/sagnik/y2h//data/trimmed_reads/S1_STAR_transcriptome_trimmed_vector_containingAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam.idxstats) | awk '$3>0 && $4>0'|awk '{a[NR]=$0;x+=(b[NR]=$3)}END{while(++i<=NR)print a[i]" "100*b[i]/x}'|sort -grk5,5 > /home/bigdata/sagnik/y2h//data/trimmed_reads/S1_STAR_transcript_read_coverage.txt
```

Comment: Don't **ever** use string concatenation to generate shell commands -- that way lies serious security bugs.

Comment: And `os.system()` uses `/bin/sh`. Your code is written to only work with bash.

Comment: BTW, why all the separate `awk` invocations? I can't see why you couldn't do everything with just one (or in native Python, with no awk *or* shell).

Comment: ...btw, this question would probably be better received if it included the exact error message given when the code were executed `<(` is a syntax error in `/bin/sh`, and that error should be emitted to stderr).

Answer (score 0):

`os.system()` uses `/bin/sh`. Your code requires bash.

Thus, the smallest change that fixes the most immediate and obvious problems is:

```
subprocess.check_call(['bash', '-c', command])
```

---

That said, a saner implementation (both more readable *and* more secure, since it doesn't allow filenames to be parsed as code by the shell) would look like:

```
cmd=r'''

dd_y2h=$1
library=$2

input1="${dd_y2h}/data/trimmed_reads/S${library}_STAR_transcriptome_vector_freeAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam.idxstats"
input2="${dd_y2h}/data/trimmed_reads/S${library}_STAR_transcriptome_trimmed_vector_containingAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam.idxstats"
output="${dd_y2h}/data/trimmed_reads/S${library}_STAR_transcript_read_coverage.txt"

paste \
  <(awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' "$input1") \
  <(awk '{print $3}' "$input2") \
  | awk '$3>0 && $4>0' \
  | awk '
      {
        a[NR]=$0;
        x+=(b[NR]=$3)
      }
      END {
        while (++i<=NR) {
          print(a[i] " " 100*b[i]/x)
        }
      }' \
  | sort -grk5,5 \
  >"$output"
'''

subprocess.check_call([
  'bash', '-c', cmd, '_',
  str(DATA_DIRECTORY_y2h),  # $1 in shell script
  str(library),             # $2 in shell script
])
```